# Is there a free collection of icons like the Noun Project?

Tags: images

I am wondering if there a free collection of icons or images that I can download like the [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/) that correlates an image for each word or noun in the dictionary.

Comment: Would https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html work?

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer, the link from that link to the 80 million tiny images project is useful, except the download is waaay too large!

Comment: @abrny, ImageNet is based upon WordNet...